# How to add a calendar event via MacOS Spotlight?

Tags: calendar, spotlight

I use Spotlight for several tasks besides simple searching.  I can calculate, convert metrics, look for an address, know the weather.

A rather simple task that I can't find is: add a calendar event.

With Siri, I can ask: "Remember me to..." But I prefer to write than speak these, especially in the work environment.

Is there a way to use Spotlight to add an event in MacOS?